# TV not recognized when using HDMI Extender - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Good night, in advance I appreciate the time taken to help solve this problem, which basically lies in that LG TV is not recognized when using an HDMI extender with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop ACER ES1-111. At the end of the installation of Ubuntu 16.04, I tried the extension of a second screen using a HDMI cable of 3 meters in length and my TV PHILIPS, in this test everything went very well, because the TV was detected by the system and can project on it.

Then take the laptop to the place where it will be used (In a small auditorium), being there note that to project use an HDMI Extender for 30 meters using LAN cable 5e, however when connecting the laptop to the HDMI Extender which in turn is connected to the LG TV in the auditorium, was not recognized by the system, so I could not use the TV to project as I did with the one in my house. If someone has spent the same or have any notion of how you can solve it, I will thank you very much.